# Delete record on timer + one condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js, database

My program is an online game. I create a game object which contains players. I want to remove the game record after 3 hours if no other player (than the one who created the game) joined the game.
I can count players, and I know about mongodb TTL but how can I set a TTL that will only trigger is there is no multiple players?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics of using a TTL index is that the document will be deleted after the specified seconds has passed from the time recorded in the index field. What may not be clearly apparent is that though the [documentation examples](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/) use a field called "createdAt", this does not mean this is your only restriction, as the date field can be updated.

So for instance if you create a document and give it an "updatedAt" field, that you populate when the game is created, then provide the index definition:

```js
db.games.createIndex({ "updatedAt": 1 },{ "expireAfterSeconds": 10800 })
```

Then all you really have to do is "update" that value whenever a new player joins the game, or there is some other action that keeps the game "valid":

```js
db.games.update(
   { "_id": gameId },
   {
       "$push": { "players": newPlayer },
       "$currentDate": { "updatedAt": true }
   }
)
```

Or change score:

```js
db.games.update(
   { "_id": gameId },
   {
       "$inc": { "score": 20 },
       "$currentDate": { "updatedAt": true }
   }
)
```

Also using the [**`$currentDate`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/) operator if you choose.

So the "expire date" for a TTL index is not "set", it just works on a process that checks the "current time" and removes any data where the indexed field of a TTL index is older than the current time "minus" the expiry seconds set on the index.

In short, create the index and just keep updating the field to keep the document current. As things change, players join or leave update the field.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but this will still delete the record after 10800 seconds after a second player joined? I don't want to delete anything if another player joined. The goal is to clean my db which has some game that other ppl never joined

Comment: @dkx22 The "key" thing I am talking about is you "constantly" update the timestamp, with every action in the game. That is what it keeping it "fresh" and only when there is "in-action" will no updates occur. Do you understand the intent now?

Comment: Gotcha and actually learned something here. But now let's say I use this and 2 players have finished a game. So that game won't be updated anymore and therefore be deleted. How can I prevent this? I could move the completed games in another model I guess but I'd rather just keep them in game

Comment: @dkx22. So let's say 2 players are just sitting there doing nothing, let's even say they went AFK and forgot to sign out? Do you leave the game sitting there forever? Or do you clean it up at some stage? At the end of the day you can write your own timer process with your own logic if you want to. But ask yourself are you really gaining anything from the effort? Does it really matter to you to keep inactive games around forever? Why even expire them at all?. These are the real questions, that only you can actually answer. I'm just staing what you can do, without needing to code another process

Comment: @dkx22 In other words "No, a TTL index cannot have other conditions" so if you can work within the contraints then use it. If not, code your own process to do the clean up.

Comment: Well you can't logout from my game, you can but then the game is over. Same if you idle for more than few minutes.
I'm marking your answer as valid since you gave me enough information to go on, thanks